why YOLO models multiple the loss by batch size in detection head?
here
return loss.sum() * batch_size, loss.detach()  # loss(box, cls, dfl)

This line is from yolov8, but I saw similar thing in v5 too.
So far I only see this kind of practice in YOLO.
I wonder what is the reason behind it.
The loss before the multiplication is actually averaged by the amount of ground truth boxes, which means the number of positive samples.
This totally make sense, because we can have different amount of positive samples per batch.
The batch size is actually do not related to the total loss value in a mini batch in detection task IMHO.
Someone asked same question, but I cannot understand the answer at all.

The multiplication of loss by the batch size in v8DetectionLoss is a common practice which effectively averages the loss over the batch. It allows for the loss to be consistent regardless of the batch size, ensuring that the scale of the updates to the model weights remains balanced as the batch size changes.

multiplication does not average it, divide does. Also a size 10 batch can only have 1 positive samples, a size 2 batch can have 100 positive samples.
Even if the multiplication can effectively averages it, it should NOT. Because batch size does not really related to sample size in detection task.
I hope someone can give me a detailed explanation: why they multiple the batch size and why it even works?

I feel this might related to the effect of batch size on model generalizability. Usually model has worse generalization with large batch size. However, increase the learning rate compensates it. The yolo training script does not scale the learning rate by batch size, instead they scale the loss, which actually has the same effect.
